# Sub-groups of $\text{Aut}(\Bbb C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This might be a very silly question, but I really have problem understanding that.

I am supposed to show that all subgroups of $\text{Aut}(\mathbb{C})$ with no fixed points are either 
$$\langle z\mapsto z+w\rangle$$
for $w\not=0$ or 
$$\langle z\mapsto z+w_1, z\mapsto z+w_2\rangle$$
for $w_1/w_2\not\in\mathbb{R}$.

What I don't understand is that for example why 
$$\langle z\mapsto z+1, z\mapsto z+\sqrt{2}\rangle$$
 is not a subgroup?

Thanks

Comment: Automorphisms of what, exactly?

Comment: By Aut(C) I mean conformal automorphisms of the plane, $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Mariano is puzzled, as am I, because when one says $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb C)$, one *usually* means the complex numbers with the usual addition and multiplication, but there are only two such automorphisms. I think you *probably* mean automorphisms of the group $\langle \Bbb C, +\rangle$, but would like you to be explicit.

Comment: @Cohlan, then you probably know that the only conformal automorphisms are the complex affine maps and their conjugates,  guess?

Comment: Oh sorry for the confusion. I am talking about Holomorphic bijections $f:\mathbb{C}\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ with the functions composition operator. I thought it was clear from the subgroups I was talking about. Sorry again.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez. Yes I do. The thing I don't understand is that why the set I mentioned above is not a subgroup with no fixed point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ is meant to mean the holomorphic bijections of $\mathbb C$, then the claim is very false.

Indeed, given *any* subgroup $\Gamma\subseteq\mathbb C$ of the additive group, the set $\{z\mapsto z+\gamma:\gamma\in\Gamma\}$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb C)$ in which the only element fixing a point is the identity.

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me. Maybe I am missing something about the question. Anyways, Thanks!